# find hostname and current user of all computers on my network

Tags: linux, command-line, shell-script

I want to get the hostname and user info who is currently loggedin on the network.

It can be a shell script or a command.

I have tried the following, but it only states the connected ipaddress.

```
for ip in $(perl -e '$,="\n"; print 1 .. 254;') ; do ping -t 1 -c 1 192.168.0.$ip>/dev/null; [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "192.168.0.$ip UP" || : ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

> [root@localhost ~]# rwho

If above command not installed then install by using

> [root@localhost ~]# yum install rwho

The rwho command produces output similar to who, but for all machines on the local network.

for more info

[root@localhost ~]# man rwho